SharePoint List lookup doesn't show choice option
I have two lists: Assets and Users
In the Users list I have columns called FirstName(Text), Location(choice), Dept(choice).
In the Assets list I have columns called Users, Location, Dept. 
I want to populate the Users field with data from FirstName.  I also want to pull data from Location and Dept fields automatically when I type the FirstName.
I go to the Assets list settings and create a new column. type: Lookup. I pick the Users list to get information from. I select the column FirstName. I want to add columns to show additional fields: Location and Dept but these options do not show up. What am I missing?

Choice column cannot be selected as an associated column in a lookup column.
One workaround is to create on the source list a calculated column of type Text with the choice value. Next, you can select this calculated column.
So, in your case:

On Users list, create a new column LocationCalc of type calculated with the formula =[Location]
On Users list, create a new column DeptCalc of type calculated with the formula =[Dept]
On Assets, on the User lookup column, you can now check LocationCalc and DeptCalc.

Source: How to Use Choice Field in Lookup Columns in SharePoint?

Your answer looked promising, but when I tried to do it and I enter the formula it errors out (Sorry, something went wrong) and it kicks me out to the site page.
